# How to save the live streaming webcam video frame by frame in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webcam

I want to store my live streaming webcam video frame by frame in the following way
frame1.jpg, frame2.jpg, frame3.jpg... in a directory. I am able to live stream the video on browser but I am still unable to save it frame by frame. JavaScript code is given below.

```
          function start(){
            var localstream;

              if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia !== null) {
                  var options = { 
                       video:true, 
                       audio:false 
                  };  
                  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(options, function(stream){

                      vid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                      localstream = stream;
                      vid.play();
                      console.log("streaming");

                  },function(e) { 

                      console.log("background error : " + e.name);
                  }); 
              }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

It involves using a Canvas on which you draw what's going on in your video, and then saving a picture from the Canvas. Complete tutorial over here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can save a web camera, frame by frame (something like this would work for you):

```
var preview = document.querySelector("#your-canvas")
var ctx = preview.getContext('2d')
setInterval(function () {
   ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 640, 360);
   preview.toBlob(function(blob) {
        // Save Blob
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = _generateGuid();
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
   });      
}, 1000 / frameRate) // adjust this for your desired FPS
```